# Match characters via regex in a string mutliple times

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurences in a string with a regex using a `Pattern` object, but it only replaces the odd occurences:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\W|\\\\N)(recursive)(\\W|$)", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(p.matcher("i-i-i").replaceAll("$1I$3"));
```

This returns me:

```
I-i-I
```

But I need to to match also the I in the middle, but somehow it doesn't catch that. I also tried a simplified regex `(^|-)(I)($|-)` and try to do the same with `i-i-i-i-i-i` which returned me `I-i-I-i-I-i`.

I guess it is because the odd dashs (at 4x+1) were already matched, so they can't be matched a second time for the even `i`s. Is it possible to allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you are trying to use same character `-` in few matches. In that case you should probably use look-around mechanism. For example you can change your

```
(^|-)(I)($|-)
```

patter to

```
(^|-)(I)(?=($|-))
```

and as replacement use `$1I`. This way regex will only check if after `I` exists `$` or `-` but will not include it in match, so

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|-)(I)(?=($|-))",
        Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(p.matcher("i-i-i-i-i-i").replaceAll("$1I"));
```

prints

```
I-I-I-I-I-I
```